# How to detect home button pressed in Cordova?

Tags: ios, cordova, events, dom-events, hybrid-mobile-app

I am facing some problem after user click on home button and kill the application in iOS. Application is developed using Cordova.

I want to detect When user clicked on home button in iOS. Is there any Cordova events which get fired when user click on Home Button?

Comment: pause event fired when application from background to foreground. So puase event is not useful for me.

Comment: as per documentation, [here](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/cordova/events/events.html#pause) pause event is called when app is going in background. check once again.

Comment: Yes right, I have test. pause event is get fired when home button clicked.

Comment: SO if your issue is resolved. Can I add the same in answer? so the question will be closed and also others needy will get to know answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After testing in device, "pause" event get fired when user clicked on home button in ios application which is developed using cordova.

```
document.addEventListener("pause", function(){
//get fired pause event occured 
console.log("pause event is fired"); 
}, false):
```

Comment: This actually not detects HOME BUTTON events. The callback will be called in every pause event such as phone call or multitasking button.